# Can you attack while jumping?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, attack

The [section on Movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Jumping) gives the following rules for long jumping:

> **Jumping**
> Your Strength determines how far you can jump.
>
> **Long Jump.** When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet up to
> your Strength score if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately
> before the jump. When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only
> half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs
> a foot of movement.
>
> This rule assumes that the height of your jump doesn't matter, such as
> a jump across a stream or chasm. At your DM's option, you must succeed
> on a DC 10 Strength (Athletics) check to clear a low obstacle (no
> taller than a quarter of the jump's distance), such as a hedge or low
> wall. Otherwise, you hit it.
>
> When you land in difficult terrain, you must succeed on a DC 10
> Dexterity (Acrobatics) check to land on your feet. Otherwise, you land
> prone.

The section on Movement and Position also gives the following:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed. You can use as much or as little of your speed as you like on your turn, following the rules here.
> Your movement can include jumping, climbing, and swimming. These different modes of movement can be combined with walking, or they can constitute your entire move. However you're moving, you deduct the distance of each part of your move from your speed until it is used up or until you are done moving.
>
> **Breaking Up Your Move**
> You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action. For example, if you have a speed of 30 feet, you can move 10 feet, take your action, and then move 20 feet.

related:
[Can you jump in combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49836/60913)
[Can I cast a spell in the middle of jumping with a Jump spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/66943/60913)
[By RAW, does jumping in combat need any special treatment?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158827/60913)

Comment: How is this question different than [the one you mentioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49836/60913)?

Comment: Is there a reason the casting a spell question doesn't answer yours? In other words, is there something that makes you believe you could cast a spell but not make an attack?

Comment: @MivaScott https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/49837/60913 only asks and answers whether jumping is possible in combat not whether you can attack while jumping.

Comment: @Medix2 Looking at the answer to https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/66978/60913 it does seem to apply so long as its conclusion isn't exclusive to spells.